# Scanner issue with math text and too many tokens

Tags: java.util.scanner, textinput

So, i am trying to make a java, text based calculator but scanner is giving me a hell of a headache.  Here is a code snipit...

```
    Scanner input=new Scanner(in);
    while (input.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(input.next()+".");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
```

My input is this: "1 + cake(3,4,6,10*30+sin(4)) * 3"
and my output SHOULD be this: "1.+.cake(3,4,6,10*30+sin(4)).*.3."

Scanner should only tokenize the whitespace, but this is what i get:
"1.+.cake.(.3.,.4.,.6.,.10.*.30.+.sin.(.4.).).*.3."

for some reason it removes every space, but also separates every single word, number and bit of punctuation!
Now i have done some homework and tried various delimiters using input.useDelimiter(String in).
Some of the ones i have used are: "\s" "\s+" "\s*" "\s*+" "[ ]" and many more but to no avail.  what am i doing wrong!?!?!?!?!

Comment: have you tried input.useDelimiter("\\s+"); // put this right above the while

Comment: Yes, the input.useDelimiter("XXXXX"); i used was right there, where XXXXX is each one of the ones i listed.  and for some reason it removed the extra slash I had in front of the s.  I even went through my input sting printing on character per line to make sure there wern't surprise characters...

Comment: have you tried.. String[] tokens = in.split("\\s+");

Comment: just did and i got the same output, the same problem, but with diffrent code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the StringTokenizer instead.

```
public class demo 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("1 + cake(3,4,6,10*30+sin(4)) * 3");
             while (st.hasMoreTokens()) 
             {
                 System.out.println(st.nextToken());
             }
    }
}
```